# Angularjs $http service with method JSONP sending data not working

Tags: angularjs

In Angularjs Can we send data using $http service with method "JSONP"

```
     $http({
        method: 'JSONP',
        url: 'http://plv.localhost/register?callback=JSON_CALLBACK',
        data  : { name : 'some name' }
      }).success(function(data, status , header, config){
           console.log('success');
      }).error(function(data, status , header, config){
           console.log('error');
      });
```

Comment: Yes you can use `JSONP`. What is the error, etc? You are not giving us much information.

Comment: @SamV i want to pass  data  : { name : 'some name' } so on server side (PHP) i can access $_POST['name']

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can! See [`ng.$http`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#methods_jsonp). Your `url` is missing the `callback` parameter:

```
$http({
    method: 'jsonp',
    url: 'http://plv.localhost/register?callback=JSON_CALLBACK',
    params: { name: 'some name' }
}).success(function(data, status , header, config) {
    console.log('success');
}).error(function(data, status , header, config) {
    console.log('error');
});
```

Comment: still data  : { name : 'some name' } is not passing in request body

Comment: the problem is angular use GET method for JSONP request so how can we send the post parameters ?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Use `params` instead of `data`. Remember, JSONP is a simple `GET` request, so there is no message body.

Comment: ["You can no longer use the `JSON_CALLBACK` string as a placeholder for specifying where the callback parameter value should go"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp). Use this instead: `$http.jsonp('some/trusted/url', {jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback'})`